# 好客 vs 亲切 - both mean hospitable?

Tags: vocabulary

So, I am trying to establish the difference in usage between these two words: 好客 and 亲切.

好客 comes out as 'hospitable, friendly'

亲切 as comes out as 'hospitable, friendly' but with an added portion of 'amicable'

Is there an obvious difference in usage between the two or are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are actually quite different.

『好客』means someone is willing to be visited by guests, so hospitable is correct understanding. It's more focused on visiting related stuff.

『亲切』basically means kind and warm. You don't need to be 『好客』 to be 『亲切』. You often use it when you feel someone is generally kind in his/her interaction with you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification!